# jQuery/javascript specific word detect

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keypress

I am wondering if it's possible to detect words input. I have 2 options:

1. The word to be written in an input, and at Enter press to fire a certain command like animate or go to url.
2. The word to be written anywhere on the page, like GTA cheats, or some YouTube Easter Eggs.

If I'm not being clear, just say and i'll edit.

Comment: when you mean written, do you mean just to detect a series of keypresses anywhere on the page?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you having problems with your implementation?

Comment: @JustinL. Yes, a series of keys. Or a word in the input.

Comment: @Blender Yes, can you help me with some code? An example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a keypress listener to body, append the chars to a string and compare it to a target word:

```
var word = "hello";
var input = "";
document.body.addEventListener('keypress',function(ev){
    input += String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode);
    console.log(input);
    if(input == word){
        alert('typed hello');
        input = "";
    }
});

// reset input when pressing esc
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27) input = "";
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/9GC4N/

Comment: It works! Thanks man! :) You derserve a beer!
http://photoshopistul.netii.net/
try writing the name of the red plummer who's always high on shrooms ;)

Comment: @yomisimie Nice! Glad i could help. thanks i'll get myself a beer if you insist :D

Comment: Hey. Small problem: the code works, but if i make it play a sound, the input does not reset. I can't insert another input word. I have to press escape. If I make it change pages, it works because the code reloads. Any ideas?

Comment: @yomisimie hey, i saw on your page you're creating a new eventlistener for each of your eastereggs. it would be better though if you only used one and then check for each word in an `if..elseif` or `switch` block. I don't know if that's your problem exactly but it could mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

***An improvement:***

```
var seq = "rainbow"
var input = ""
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)

    for (var i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] != seq[i] && input[i] != undefined) {
            input = ""
        }
    }

    if (input == seq) {
        alert("EASTER EGG!")

        input = ""
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to use a queue as that way we always compare the last x characters with the target sequence after every key press.

E.g.

```
var seq = 'upsidedown';
var input = '';
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    // Add the latest character to the end of the queue
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    // If the queue is longer than the target sequence remove the first character
    if(input.length > seq.length) {
        input = input.substr(1);
    }

    // Check for a match
    if(input == seq) {
        alert("EASTER EGG!")
    }

})
```